# Get Major and Minor Value when ScanPeripheral

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working with Bluetooth Low Energy. I want to get Major and Minor value to decide which one bluetooth that I want to connect.
I only get major and minor when doing monitoring and ranging (using Proximity UUID).

How to get major and minor when doing scanPeripheral or how to get peripheral ID when doing monitoring & ranging ?

Comment: You can't. iBeacons are only visible via Core Location. BLE peripherals are only visible by Core Bluetooth. If you have a device that is both an iBeacon and a BLE peripheral then you need to connect to the peripheral in order to interrogate any characteristics it has, such as characteristics that set the iBeacon values; there is no relationship between the beacon data and the core Bluetooth peripheral identifier

Comment: can I add "major" and "minor" information in advertisement data ble ? so I can major and minor value when doing scanPeripheral.

Comment: Yes, you could add it to the manufacturer data; https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbadvertisementdatamanufacturerdatakey